# Planes contours fitting

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have a specific issue of 3D planes border fitting. Here's an example of what I am trying to do (in 2D) :

[image: Plane fitting]
*2D planes border fitting*

My first idea is to search for a point of a contour the closest points of each neighbor contours and find the median point, but it is costly to perform this search, plus they are some issues.

Any idea and/or publications on this problem ?

*Edit : It seems I am not specific enough. The contours I have are oriented and made of 3D points. Here's an example of my actual output :*
[image: PlaneOutput]

*The goal is to "merge" the neighbor contours.*

*Edit 2: The idea of straight skeleton by Ante is good in 2D, but they are several issues in 3D. The general idea is to compute the polygon formed by the point of the current neighbor contours, and project them on the straight skeleton/median axis of the polygon. But in 3D this polygon is not necessary flat (in my case it's never flat), so you have to find a plane in order to project the points. Which can cause some mistakes.*

*I have a solution that works for planes that intersect with an angle of more than 30 degrees. Identify the neighbor points of each planes, compute the intersection line and project the points on the line.*

Comment: Looks like [straight skeleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton).

Comment: Have you considered using a spatial tree?  You would only have to test contours in the same leaf nodes.

Comment: @Ante: yes, I could also considered a discretized median axis
DeepYellow: i already have a structure for localization, but thanks I didn't this one !

Comment: what about filling all space between close contours with collor of contour and apply thinning algorithm ? But it can cause small shape distortions

Comment: also you can compute the intersection of neighbouring planes if you have the 3D data  ... as i can see some planes are not planes but curved surfaces so consider just small local area near processed border point as plane and after that just join theese points as new border line btw is the data aquired by kinect at any chance ?  (just curious)

Comment: @Spektre The intersection would work only if the planes have 2 really different normals. It would work for the purple and red planes, but not for the green and red planes. And all the planes are planes ;) The data is acquired with an Asus Xtion, but it's the same techno with Kinect.